# How to use the dot notation in a kanban view in Odoo?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I have a model `customer` and another model `company`. The model `customer` has a field named `company_id`, which is a *Many2one* pointing to `company`. Besides, `company` has a field of type *Char* named `trade_name`.

Now, I'm creating the kanban view of `customer`, using **Qweb**. What I want is to show the trade name of the company of each customer.

```
<t t-field="company_id.trade_name"/>
```

That line is not working, I get a blank space in the kanban view where the field should be. I also tried with `t-esc`, and writing `<field...>` as I'd do with a tree or form view, but they don't accept the dot notation.

I know it perfectly works in reports. What about kanban views? How can I manage such a simple task?

Comment: For the moment, I have not found a solution for this. I did a workaround: I've declared a field `company_trade_name` in `res_partner`, which is a char related to `'company_id.trade_name'`. That way I can use it on a kanban view. But if someone finds a better way, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

In your case basically,

`web_kanban` module is used to manage all the classes related with the kanban view.

Which is used to display the element into the kanban card and you can easily drag and drop facility on it.

Kanban View is totally mixer of Tree and Form all to gather.

**Kanban Tamplate :-**

kanban view must define at least one tamplate Kanban-box which will be rendered once for each record.

so that hear **record is the global object** and you can access the every field with the help of record object.

**Need to follow the below Way :**

Add your field entry into the kanban card and then after you can access that field with the template tag of kanban view through global record object.

```
<div t-if="record.company_id.trade_name.raw_value">
   <t t-esc="record.company_id.trade_name.value"/>
</div>
```

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Comment: After several years I have to do almost the same task again with a kanban view, and I am still wondering how to do that without using a related field. I did not try your solution in version 8 but in version 11 it seems that it does not work: printing `<t t-esc="record.parent_id.comercial.value"/>` or `<t t-esc="record.parent_id.comercial.raw_value"/>` returns nothng (I have updated the field names as in newer versions of Odoo partners have the field `comercial` for the trade name).