# How to access one2many fields values on Kanban view odoo 0.8?

Tags: python, xml, odoo-8, kanban

I need to loop over the records of o2m filed in kanban to show what I need from the other model.

all i need in kanban view to do this

```
<t t-foreach="o2m_field" t-as"record">
    <t t-esc="record.name"/>
</t>
```

Is that possible to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

This question is a duplicate to [Is it possible to show an One2many field in a kanban view in Odoo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805475/is-it-possible-to-show-an-one2many-field-in-a-kanban-view-in-odoo) but here is a link to a module from Serpent Consulting which will be able to do what you are looking for.

https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/8.0/web_one2many_kanban/

Here is a little more info.

```
<kanban>
    <field name="one2manyFieldname"/>
    <templates>
        <t t-name="kanban-box">
            <div class="oe_kanban_content">
                <p>
                   <t t-foreach="record.one2manyFieldname.raw_value" t-as='o'>
                       <t t-esc="o.name"/><br/>
                   </t>
                </p>
            </div>
        </t>
    </templates>
</kanban>
```

The important part is before the template tag you have to pass through your one2many field so it is available within your template. Then you must access the record's "raw_value" and give it an alias. Like this.

```
 <t t-foreach="record.one2manyFieldname.raw_value" t-as='o'>
```

Then you can access the properties of the record.

Within the scope of the t-foreach tag you can access properties of the record, like this.

```
<t t-foreach="record.one2manyFieldname.raw_value" t-as='o'>
    ID: <t t-esc="o.id"/><br/>
    Name: <t t-esc="o.name"/><br/>
    Write Date: <t t-esc="o.write_date"/><br/>
    Write UID: <t t-esc="o.write_uid"/><br/>
    Some Property: <t t-esc="o.some_property"/><br/>
    <br/>
</t>
```

You should be able to access the properties of each record you have aliased (in this case as 'o'). Do not take the above too literally. The layout and styling of your html and css are up to you. As well as the properties of your record you choose to display.

Many2one values are provided as a tuple. Access the many2one properties like this.

```
Many2one ID: <t t-esc="o.partner_id[0]"/>
Many2one Name: <t t-esc="o.partner_id[1]"/>
```

Comment: what i did 
1 - install web_one2many_kanban
2- wrote down this code in my module 
`<record id="kanban-zoser-book" model="ir.ui.view"><field name="name">zoser.book.kanabn</field><field name="model">zoser.book</field><field name="type">kanban</field><field name="arch" type="xml"><kanban><templates><t t-name="kanban-box"><field name="name"/><t t-foreach="o2m_field" t-as"record"> <t t-esc="record.name"/></t><field name="book_ads"/></t></templates></kanban></field></record>
`
And i got this error
No enumerator given to foreach ,

Comment: Thank you for your great help, everything work fine now.

Comment: Do you have any idea about the many2one field how to access the values of that field because it only returned id and the name ??

Comment: I really do not know. There may be an equivalent module for many2many or it is possible the module supports many2many. Sorry I cant be more helpful.

Comment: This works. But when I try to add two one2many fields in the same kanban view, the data in the first one2many is displayed as blank. Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

For Odoo14

```
<!-- Your parent form groups and field goes here -->    
        
<field name="your_one2many_field" nolabel="1">
    <kanban class="o_kanban_mobile">
        <templates>
            <t t-name="kanban-box">
                <div t-attf-class="oe_kanban_global_click">                 
                    <div class="oe_kanban_details">                     
                        <div class="o_kanban_record_top">
                            <div class="o_kanban_record_headings">                  
                                <strong class="o_kanban_record_title">Title Goes Here</strong>                  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <b>Label 1: </b><field name="field_1"/><br/>
                        <b>Label 2: </b> <field name="field_2"/><br/>
                        <b>Label 3:</b> <field name="field_3"/><br/>   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </t>
        </templates>
    </kanban>
    <form>
        your_one2many_field form goes here....
    </form>
</field>
```

Reference: **[Kanban in One2Many Field](https://learnopenerp.blogspot.com/2021/09/display-access-one2many-field-value-kanban-view-odoo14.html)**